# Absolute value proof

Tags: ordered-fields

Prove that $|xy|=|x||y|$

hint: consider the 4 cases, x and y both positive, both negative, x is positive while y is negative, and y is positive while x is negative.

I am not really sure how to go about proving this, especially the last 2 cases. A push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Proof: There are 4 cases.

Suppose that x>0 and y>0, then $|xy|=xy=|x||y|$

Suppose x<0 and y<0, then $|xy|=-x*-y=xy=|x||y|$

Suppose x<0 and y>0, then

Suppose x>0 and y<0 then

Comment: The important thing to remember is that when x<0, |x|=-x>0. And if only one of x and y is negative, then xy is also negative. So you need to be a bit more careful with your x<0 and y<0 case, but otherwise you're practically there.

Answer (score 1):

For my taste, you're missing some connecting reasoning in the two cases you've already done. Let me show you the "both negative case" with a more solid argument:

> Suppose $x$ and $y$ are both negative. Then $|x|=-x$ and $|y|=-y$. Also $xy$ is positive so $|xy|=xy$. Therefore, $$ |xy|=xy=(-x)\cdot(-y)=|x|\cdot|y| $$

The same scheme can be used for the other cases.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 3:** Suppose that $x < 0$ and $y \geq 0$. Then $xy \leq 0$ so that:
$$
|xy| = -xy = (-x)(y) = |x||y|
$$
as desired.

---

The other case is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : |$x$|$ = x$ for $x\ge 0$ $\ \ \ \ \ \ $
        |$x$|$ =-x$ for $x<0$