# Spivak's explanation Ch 1, Q 12.1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

> Prove $|xy| = |x|\cdot|y|$

There have been many answers, ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1917860/prove-xy-x-cdot-y),[2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305118/proof-verification-xy-x-cdot-y),[3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759913/spivak-calculus-3rd-edition-chapter-1-problem-12-i-and-ii-proofs-critique),[4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1004941/absolute-value-proof/1004958#1004958),)

But, I would like to ask about Spivak's answer, as it most likely gives an insight that would be helpful.

> $(|xy|)^{2} = (xy)^{2} = x^{2}y^{2} = |x|^{2}|y|^{2} = (|x|\cdot|y|)^{2}$ Sińce $|xy|$ and $|x|\cdot|y|$ arę both $>0$, this proves that $|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|$

Just about all the answers referenced make use of individual cases as a proof. Spivak, in this proof, seems to rely heavily on the fact that $(-a)^{2} = (a)^{2}$ unless I am missing something. So, it is understandable that the first part of his proof is correct as any value $x,y <0$ is positive after squaring. What I am not understanding is how the last statement

> Sińce $|xy|$ and $|x|\cdot|y|$ arę both $>0$, this proves that
> $|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|$

follows the first, and justifies the proof he states.

**EDIT**

In response to one of the comments, here is what I would like clarified.

(a) Spivak has shown *If $a < 0$ and $b < 0$* then $ab>0$, which allows me to conclude that *$(xy)^2 > 0$*. and thus, *$(|xy|)^2 >0$* as Spivak shows in the first part of the proof. But, why is this even necessary, as surely *any* absolute value, for example, $|xy|$ is by definition $>0$. I would really like to understand his rationale for this.

(b) Why does the last part of his proof ( the second block quote above) even need to be justified by part *a*? It is almost as if it could stand alone.

I hope this helps clarify the question.

Comment: Write $(|xy| - |x||y|) (|xy|+|x||y|) =0$; First factor is 0, gives the result, what can yousay. about the second factor?

Comment: Note that you can demonstrate the rule of signs like I did in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3635367/399263. I showed for $(-x)(-y)=xy$ but you can adapt to $xy+(-x)y=0$ for instance. Note that the "-" symbol is not explicitly used, I consider inverse $X$ of $x$ as verifying $x+X=0$.

Comment: You should explain more precisely what you do not understand (or where you suspect a gap). Is it that $u^2 = v^2$ implies $u = v$ when $u,v \ge 0$?

Comment: @PaulFrost  I have edited the question to help clarify the gist of my concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $(|xy|)^{2} = (xy)^{2} = x^{2}y^{2} = |x|^{2}|y|^{2} = (|x|\cdot|y|)^{2}$. Since $|xy|$ and $|x|\cdot|y|$ arę both $>0$, this proves that $|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|$.

It seems that you want to understand what Spivak motivated to give the above proof and which ingredients are possibly dispensable. In fact he uses exactly two ingredients:

1. $u^2 = \lvert u \rvert^2$. It is applied for $u = xy$ and $u = x, y$.
2. If $u, v \ge 0$, then $u^2 = v^2$ implies $u = v$. It is applied for $u = \lvert xy \rvert$, $v = \lvert x \rvert \cdot \lvert y \rvert$.

None of these "lemmas" can be dropped in Spivak's approach. However, both have to be *proved formally* (which is very easy), but I couldn't find an explicit proof in Spivak's book.

Therefore I agree to you that it would be more transparent to prove directly that $|xy|=|x|\cdot|y|$. To do so, you have to consider the four  cases $x \ge 0, y \ge 0$ / $x \ge 0, y \le 0$ etc. But 1. requires two cases and 2. requires 6.(d) which is by no means easier or more elegant than the direct proof.

Comment: Paul, thank you for clarifying this. It really does help to have someone help to see the "forest", as many times, especially at the start of a "journey" like this, the trees are all you see, and then often only barely.